# Normalization in Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I know that normalization in Cassandra is considered an anti pattern, but what can be done if the storage requirement it implies is just too high?

For example, we currently have a large table of "feeds" that are distributed to many recipients, so the current schema is something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE feed_items_duplicated(recipient_id int, feed_id timeuuid, 
   <data columns d1 to dn> 
  PRIMARY KEY ((recipient_id), feed_id);
```

In this schema everything is nice and the feeds are easily fetched for a single recipient using a single range query over the feed id:

```
SELECT * from feed_items_duplicated where recipient_id = 123 
   and feed_id > minTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100');
```

The problem is that a single feed can be distributed to hundreds of recipients and each row can be quite massive with the columns d1 to dn duplicated in every single one of them.

In order to contain storage requirements we thought of another option

```
CREATE TABLE feed_items(recipient_id int, feed_id timeuuid, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((recipient_id), feed_id);
CREATE TABLE feed_data(feed_id timeuuid, <data columns d1 to dn> 
  PRIMARY KEY (feed_id);
```

This would still require running the query above with an additional query run after that:

```
SELECT * from feed_data where feed_id in (f1, f2, f3...);
```

So question 1: Is it a good idea to perform the above query, as it will most likely hit all the nodes in the cluster? How bad is it comparing to performing a dedicated query for every f1 through fn in parallel?

Another approach would be creating an arbitrary clustering key within a small limited range (lets say [1-20]) for feed_data table so that we'll only have up to 20 queries of the following type to execute:

```
SELECT * from feed_data where group_id = 1 and feed_id in (f1, f3, ...);
SELECT * from feed_data where group_id = 2 and feed_id in (f2, ...);
```

This approach limits every query to a single executing node, but with such a low cardinality partition key is it possible to ensure that the data will be distributed equally between nodes?

Answer (score 0):

question 1: It is worth trying if possible access-time degradation is acceptable for recipients. There is number of recommendations and warnings about 'in' clause in CQL queries from [DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) and [other](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/) nice [guys](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/11/05/breaking-down-the-cql-where-clause/). Instead of 'in' queries I'd rather think about [on-board caching](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_configuring_caches_c.html).

question 2: If your data-columns [d1...dn] are small and not vary dramatically from one to other then I think it should't be an issue. I think data-items grouping is good idea if it brings you data-reuse ability. So you can organize your feed data like: feed1 = bundle1 + bundle2, feed2 = bundle1 + bundle3 etc, where bundle1 = data-item1 + data-item2, bundle2 = data-item3 etc.

from myself: If you not sure with data-structure optimization strategy then maybe it is worth trying to introduce some kind of eviction policy for your feed data? Like TTL or smth else.
So, you can leave your "real-time" tables as they are and move obsolete data to more space-efficient storage or even delete it.